# Spatie Laravel sitemap generated xml file is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-sitemap

I am developing a Laravel application. Now, I am trying to implement the sitemap for my website using this package, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap. But when I generate sitemap.xml, no paths are included in the file.

I installed the package running the Composer command

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap
```

Then I published the Composer.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

In the routes/web.php, I added this.

```
Route::get('sitemap', function () {
    SitemapGenerator::create('http://app.localhost/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
    return "Sitemap generated".
});
```

When I run the code and sitemap.xml is generated. When I opened the sitemap.xml, that is all I found in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</urlset>
```

I have many routes in the web.php. What is wrong and how can fix it?

Comment: Is your home page contains links that crawlable by the package? Actually the package working by crawling any contain links in the page. It's not reading from the routes definition.

Comment: On the home page, I put some links using anchor tags. But it is just not working or crawling

Comment: Same problem here, any update?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually add other urls like below and when you run it, the links will be added to your sitemap file:

```
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Url;

 Route::get('sitemap', function () {
    SitemapGenerator::create('https://vesicash.com/')->getSitemap()
    ->add(Url::create('/link1')->setPriority(0.5))
    ->add(Url::create('/link2')->setPriority(0.5))
    ->add(Url::create('/link3')->setPriority(0.5))
    ->add(Url::create('/privacy')->setPriority(0.5))
    ->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
    return "Sitemap Generated";
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add pages in for loop. actually my pages are dynamic.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/main/resources/views/url.blade.php

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem:

I just made sure that the `APP_URL` was set properly in **.env** file.

I added, for example: `https://example.com/` and boom it worked.

This should also work on your local pc as well.

Answer (score 1):

When I did it first time it looked same for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</urlset>
```

I think you did it on your local pc.

So first, you can test with this url.

```
SitemapGenerator::create("https://spatie.be/en")
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```

If it works well, then I believe it will work on server too.
In my case it worked on server, while it was same result with you on my local.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to anyone, don't panic**

the problem is when u clear config or when u run php artisan optimize:clear

the url will be null or ''

so solution is : `(config('app.url') ?? 'http://www.myspecialdomain.com')`

this will check if url exist if not it will use provided url.

Have a good day